# Android - compile Google play service and sync

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm struggling with compile google play service. I've got everything updated and  there is problem I can't understand. When I put

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
```

and try to sync there is a problem with

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

It's giving me this message:

"All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 25.3.1, 25.2.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1 and com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.2.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion.)"

This is the updated version of google play services. I'm not clear why this is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [release notes:](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)

> When you upgrade your app’s Play services dependencies to 11.2.0 or
>   later, your app’s build.gradle must also be updated to specify a
>   compileSdkVersion of at least 26 (Android O). This does not change the
>   way your app runs. You will not be required to update
>   targetSdkVersion. If you update compileSdkVersion to 26, you may
>   receive an error in your build with the following message referring to
>   the Android support library:
>
> This support library should should not use a different version (25) than the compileSdkVersion (26).
>
> This support library should should not use a different version (25)
>   than the compileSdkVersion (26). This error can be resolved by
>   upgrading your support library dependencies to at least version
>   26.0.0.

The solution is to update the support library to version 26.